# Storing Unsigned Char as Binary in File with C++?

Tags: c++, file, binary, printf, bit

I have written the following code to print the data in Pin and Pout to a file:

```
void run() {
while ( in.readable() >= 17*11*12+SIZE_RSPACKET &&
    out.writable() >= 1 ) {
  u8 *pin = in.rd()+17*11*12, *pend=pin+SIZE_RSPACKET;
  u8 *pout= out.wr()->data;
  for ( int delay=17*11; pin<pend;
    ++pin,++pout,delay=(delay-17+17*12)%(17*12) )
*pout = pin[-delay*12];
  in.read(SIZE_RSPACKET);
  out.written(1);

 /* Printing output after Deinterleaving to file: Need to Turn this into Binary */   

FILE * F; // Create File
F = fopen("Deinterleaving.txt", "wb"); // Open Deinterleaving File 

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_RSPACKET; i++){ // For Every Packet (204 bytes)
    // Print char for data coming and going out (Not Binary) to file
    fprintf(F, "%s %u %s %u \n", " Data coming in: ", pin[i], " Data Going Out: ", pout[i]); 

   } 
    fflush(F);
    fclose(F);
  }
}
```

This gives me the output:

```
 Data coming in:  71            Data Going Out:  0 
 Data coming in:  99            Data Going Out:  0 
 Data coming in:  46            Data Going Out:  0 
 Data coming in:  84            Data Going Out:  0 
 Data coming in:  129           Data Going Out:  0 
 Data coming in:  134           Data Going Out:  0 
 Data coming in:  1             Data Going Out:  0 
 Data coming in:  101           Data Going Out:  0 
 Data coming in:  15            Data Going Out:  1
```

How can I convert this  to it's binary counterpart for every 8 packets so that the output will look like the following?

What the output should look like (i.e. 1 block (8 Packets of 204 bytes each)):

```
71 99 46 84 129 134 1 101 -> 01000111 01100011 0101110 01010100 010000001 010000110 00000001 01100101
```

Comment: The `fprintf` is for *formatted* data (to human readable form).  Try using `fwrite` to write data, in internal represenation, to the file.  Also, the files should be open in *binary* mode so no translations take place.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews fwrite gives me a bunch of unreadable characters, even with the file open in binary mode.

Comment: Binary data is often unreadable (containing non printable ASCII codes).  Use a *hex* editor or view the file in hex or use a program (such as octal dump) that can display the contents in hex.  With experience, you can print the values in hex before printing them, try using `"0x%2X"` format for each byte (octet).

Answer (score 0):

Use `fwrite` for writing internal representation of data to a file:

```
fwrite(&pin[0], 1, sizeof(pin), F);
```

Also, open the file in a *binary* mode to avoid translations, such as the value `0x0d` being replaced by `0x0d, 0x0a`.

The `fprintf` is for transforming internal representation into human readable form.